# ListPlot3D not plotting my data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I'm writing a processor in Mathematica to get some analytics on some data I've collected via a hadoop MapReduce process.

It's a list of records in the form

```
<float>, tc:<int>, m:<int>, h:<int>; <float>
```

I do some messy processing and extract a list of tuples in the form `{<int>, <int>, <float>}` (which corresponds to x, y, z) which I want to plot using `ListPlot3D`.

```
data = (* <processed data in form of list of {<c:<int>,m:<int>,h:<int>,<float>}> *)

plotPoints = 
 Table[
   {N[Part[StringSplit[Part[x, 1], ":"], 2]], 
    N[Part[StringSplit[Part[x, 1], ":"], 2]], 
    N[Part[x, 4]]}, 
  {x, data}]
ListPointPlot3D[plotPoints, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> All]
```

In my output, the list `plotPoints` looks correct, but plotting it creates an empty plot, and using `ListPointPlot3D` gives the error

> Last {} has zero length and no last element.

This is what the output from `plotPoints` and `ListPlot3D` looks like

[image: The error I'm seeing]

#### Edit

For better debugging here is the full script:

```
data = 
    Join[
      Part[
        Part[
          Select[#, compare], 1] & /@ 
            StringSplit[Take[StringSplit[#, ";"], 1], "\t"], 
          1] & /@ #, 
      Take[Part[StringSplit[#, ";"], 3], {2}]] & 
  /@ 
    Import["nh-r-00000"]

plotPoints = 
  Table[
    {N[Part[StringSplit[Part[x, 1], ":"], 2]], 
     N[Part[StringSplit[Part[x, 1], ":"], 2]], 
     N[Part[x, 4]]}, 
   {x, data}]

ListPlot3D[plotPoints, PlotRange -> All]
```

Dataset: http://sta.sh/02dfd34p35pp

Comment: Well come to mathematica.stackexchange.com!!!!! To make it easier to get your question answered try to clarify what's "x". Also, try to generate a small dummy matrix with Ramdon[], so that we can see  all of your code.

Comment: Would you mind uploading (a small subset of) your "data I've collected via a hadoop MapReduce process" somewhere, so it can be tested out?

Comment: @J.M. I added a sta.sh link to the full dataset that I'm using for testing (as well as how i am splitting it, the splitting is a bit nasty so I wouldn't be surprised if im doing something egregious there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be a problem with your data set since random data works fine. Can't say what the problem is since you did not provide a representative sample that exhibits the problem.

```
plotPoints = {
    RandomInteger[{2000, 20000}, 100],
    RandomInteger[{2000, 20000}, 100],
    RandomReal[{10^5, 10^6}, 100]} // Transpose;
```

Verifying the form of the data

```
plotPoints[[1 ;; 3]]

(*  {{5603, 12887, 902134.}, {2059, 3254, 103759.}, {14340, 19104, 768750.}}  *)
```

Plotting the data

```
ListPointPlot3D[plotPoints, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You probably don't want to use the option `DataRange->All`

```
ListPointPlot3D[plotPoints, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> All]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Using your data

```
data = Flatten[
   Rest /@ Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Documents/_Mma Temp 2/data.txt", 
     "Table"]];
```

Examining form

```
data[[1 ;; 3]] // FullForm
```

[image]

```
data2 = ToExpression[
   StringSplit[
      StringReplace[#, {"c:" :> "", "m:" :> "", "h:" :> "", ";" :> ","}], 
      ","] & /@ data];
```

Examining form

```
data2[[1 ;; 3]] // FullForm
```

[image]

```
plotPoints = data2[[All, {1, 2, 4}]];

ListPointPlot3D[plotPoints, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: if this was a western you would be way too fast on the trigger sir!!!!

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the validation. It's pretty clear (especially after looking at Mathematica docs) that something in the way to data is being stored isn't quite right. Though it's a bit unclear because it *looks* ok in the output (like if i copy paste from output and store it is as a variable directly it works)

Comment: Yeah, this got it. I looked at my code and when I replace N with ToExpression, it started working. Now I feel pretty silly about this issue.